# Is there a way to freeze column headers in SearchKit?

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder

Is there a way to freeze a column header on a SearchKit Table display like you would on a spreadsheet? We have several SearchKit Tables that take up more than 1 page and it would be nice to have the have the column labels present when scrolling through the search results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add CSS in your theme file

```
div.crm-search-display-table table thead tr {
  position: sticky;
  top: 42px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
}
```

Comment: This worked great. The only thing we changed was adding  z-index: 2; because the hamburger menu I added was going over.